# How can multipass GroupBy() be faster than a single pass?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

I cannot understand how GroupBy() appears to perform faster for a multi pass ResultSelector than for a single pass version.

Given this class:

```
    public class DummyItem
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public decimal V1 { get; set; }
        public decimal V2 { get; set; }
    }
```

I create an array with 100,000 entries with some random data and then iterate the following query:

**APPROACH 1: Multiple passes for category totals**

```
var q = randomData.GroupBy(
   x => x.Category,
   (k, l) => new DummyItem
   {
      Category = k,
      V1 = l.Sum(x => x.V1), // Iterate the items for this category
      V2 = l.Sum(x => x.V2), // Iterate them again
    }
);
```

It appears to be double handling the inner enumerable where it sums V1 and V2 for each category.

So I put the following alternative together, presuming that this would provide better performance by calculating category totals in a single pass.

**APPROACH 2: Single pass for category totals**

```
var q = randomData.GroupBy(
    x => x.Category, 
    (k, l) => l.Aggregate( // Iterate the inner list once per category
            new decimal[2], 
            (t,d) => 
            {
                t[0] += d.V1;
                t[1] += d.V2;
                return t;
            },
            t => new DummyItem{ Category = k, V1=t[0], V2=t[1] }
    )
);
```

Fairly typical results:

```
'Multiple pass': iterations=5 average=2,961 ms each
'Single pass': iterations=5 average=5,146 ms each
```

Incredibly, Approach 2 takes up to twice as long as Approach 1. I have run numerous benchmarks varying the number of V* properties, the number of distinct categories and other factors. While the magnitude of the performance difference varies, Approach 2 is **always substantially slower** than Approach 1.

Am I missing something fundamental here? How can Approach 1 be faster than approach 2?

(I sense a facepalm coming...)

---

* UPDATE ***

After @Jirka's answer I thought it would be worth removing GroupBy() from the picture to see if simple aggregations on a large list performed as expected. The task was simply to compute the totals for the two decimal variables on the same list of 100,000 random rows.

The results continued the surprises:

**SUM: ForEach**

```
decimal t1 = 0M;
decimal t2 = 0M;
foreach(var item in randomData)
{
    t1 += item.V1;
    t2 += item.V2;
}
```

The baseline. I believe the fastest way of getting the required output.

**SUM: Multipass**

```
x = randomData.Sum(x => x.V1);
y = randomData.Sum(x => x.V2);
```

**SUM: Singlepass**

```
var result = randomData.Aggregate(new DummyItem(), (t, x) => 
{ 
     t.V1 += x.V1; 
     t.V2 += x.V2; 
     return t; 
});
```

The results were as follows:

```
'SUM: ForEach': iterations=10 average=1,793 ms each
'SUM: Multipass': iterations=10 average=2,030 ms each
'SUM: Singlepass': iterations=10 average=5,714 ms each
```

Surprisingly it reveals the issue has nothing to do with GroupBy. The behavior is consistent with data aggregation generally. My assumption that it is better to do data aggregation in a single pass is simply wrong (probably a hangover from my db roots).

(*facepalm*)

As @Jirka has pointed out the in-lining apparently occuring for the multipass approach, means it is only marginally slower than the baseline 'ForEach'. My naive attempt to optimise to a single-pass, ran almost 3 times slower!

It appears that when dealing with in-memory lists, whatever it is you wish to do with the items in the list is likely to be a far bigger factor in performance, than the iteration overhead.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your additional observations. Do not throw away your intuition. Single pass algorithms do have a performance advantage for data over approximately 1 MB. But here this advantage was dwarfed by method calls occurring in the innermost (bottleneck) loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate has to create 99,999 activation records (for non-inlineable method calls) in the process.  That offsets the advantage of the single pass.

Think of Count, Sum, Average etc. as optimized special cases of what Aggregate can do in the general case.

Comment: Thanks @Jirka. No the array is only allocated once as the seed to Aggregate. For some of my tests this was as few as four times (i.e. only four categories). When iterating the enumerable for each category the array is simply updated.

Comment: @degorolls - You are right, I am sorry for the oversight.  I corrected my answer.

Comment: Fascinating! Thanks @Jirka. I had a fairly fundamental misconception corrected...

Comment: Might it be that using Sum() is better using processor registers, cache etc? Like when you count  1 total of several multipasses it can be one processor opcode, but when you do a one pass calculation you have to Add to one summ, store, get other summ, add, store?

Comment: @Alexander - The structure DummyItem is probably some 40 bytes long, which rules out SSE optimizations theoretically available for summing up tightly packed data (.NET probably could not do that anyway).  The data is presumably a little too big to fit in L2 cache, which gives an advantage to the single pass algorithm.  However, I presume that the Sum computation is dominated by reading the input whereas the Aggregate computation by stack manipulation; the difference is only slightly compensated by the fact that the stack manipulation consists of cache hits while the input of misses.